# Blank file after make in vim

Tags: vim, makefile

When I run :make in vim, and if I have an error in my one and only cpp file (main.cpp) vim shows me the errors and when I press enter it opens a file named

```
^[[H^[[Jmain.cpp
```

instead of

```
main.cpp
```

And I have to manually reopen my file. Any idea how to tell vim to open the right file?

I'm running

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 20 2016 11:17:28) 
MacOS X (unix) version 
Included patches: 1-1655 Compiled by Homebrew
```

Error output:

```
main.cpp:40:2: error: unknown type name 'obvious'
        obvious error
        ^
main.cpp:40:15: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        obvious error
                     ^
                     ;
2 errors generated.
rm: main: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

vim errorformat (as reported by :echo &errorformat)

```
%*[^"]"%f"%*\D%l: %m,"%f"%*\D%l: %m,%-G%f:%l: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once,%-G%f:%l: for each function it appears in.),%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c:,%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c\,,%-GIn file included from %f:%l:%c,%-GIn file included from %f:%l,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l:%c,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l:,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l\,,%-G%*[ ]from %f:%l,%f:%l:%c:%m,%f(%l):%m,%f:%l:%m,"%f"\, line %l%*\D%c%*[^ ] %m,%D%*\a[%*\d]:Entering directory %*[`']%f',
%X%*\a[%*\d]: Leaving directory %*[`']%f',%D%*\a: Entering directory %*[`']%f',%X%*\a: Leaving directory %*[`']%f',%DMaking %*\a in %f,%f|%l| %m
```

Comment: Could you add the complete output of your compiler as well as the value of `errorformat`?

Answer (score 0):

Makefile looked something like this:

```
all:
    clear && g++ main.cpp -o main
```

And the clear seems to be throwing it off. Workaround is to remove the clear or add an echo after

```
all:
    g++ main.cpp -o main

all2:
    clear && echo "" && g++ main.cpp -o main
```